# C# ArrayList group using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, group-by, sql-order-by

I am currently stuck at this place. I need some help.

**Say for example this is the scenario input.**

Input : Mo-Fr 06:00-22:00, Sa 07:00-22:00, So 08:00-22:00

Formetet to database Table:

**Table name : (Opening)**

- **Day | DayNumber | Number | Open | Close**
- Mon, 1,  0:00, 22:00
- Tue, 2, 0:00, 22:00
- Wed, 3, 0:00, 22:00
- Thu, 4, 0:00, 22:00
- Fri, 5, 0:00, 22:00
- Sat, 6, 7:00, 24:00
- Sun, 0, 8:00, 24:00

**I would like to group by day range from this table**

The expected output will be like :

```
"periods": [
        {
          "open": {
            "day": 1,
            "time": "06:00"
          },
          "close": {
            "day": 5,
            "time": "22:00"
          }
        },
        {
          "open": {
            "day": 6,
            "time": "07:00"
          },
          "close": {
            "day": 6,
            "time": "24:00"
          }
        },
        {
          "open": {
            "day": 0,
            "time": "08:00"
          },
          "close": {
            "day": 0,
            "time": "24:00"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> dayNames = new List<string>(){"Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","So"};
            string input = "Mo-Fr 06:00-22:00, Sa 07:00-22:00, So 08:00-22:00";
            string[] days = input.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            var dayRange = (from d in days
                            select d.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                           .Select(x => new { days = x[0].Trim(), time = x[1].Trim() })
                           .Select(x => new {  
                               startDay = x.days.Contains("-") ? x.days.Split(new char[] {'-'})[0] : x.days,
                               endDay = x.days.Contains("-") ? x.days.Split(new char[] {'-'})[1] : x.days,
                               startTime = x.time.Contains("-") ? x.time.Split(new char[] {'-'})[0] : x.time,
                               endTime = x.time.Contains("-") ? x.time.Split(new char[] {'-'})[1] : x.time,
                           }); 

            var period = dayRange.Select(x => new {
                open = new {day = dayNames.IndexOf(x.startDay) + 1, time = x.startTime},
                close = new {day = dayNames.IndexOf(x.endDay) + 1, time = x.endTime}
            });

            string formatedPeriods = string.Join(",",period.Select(x => 
                "{\n\r\"open\": {\n\r" +
                "\"day\": " + x.open.day.ToString() + "," +   
                "\"time\": " + x.open.time.ToString() + "\n\r}," +   
               "{\n\r\"close\": {\n" +
                "\"day\": " + x.open.day.ToString() + "," +   
                "\"time\": " + x.open.time.ToString() + "\n\r}\n\r}"   
                ).ToArray());
            string output = string.Format("\"periods\": [\n\r{0}\n\r]",formatedPeriods );


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Its a good solution. but I need something like this.
I have already parse this and store it to database and this is the formet currently I am storing
`
    Day | DayNumber | Number | Open | Close
    Mon, 1, 0:00, 22:00
    Tue, 2, 0:00, 22:00
    Wed, 3, 0:00, 22:00
    Thu, 4, 0:00, 22:00
    Fri, 5, 0:00, 22:00
    Sat, 6, 7:00, 24:00
    Sun, 0, 8:00, 24:00
`
I need to get group data from this.

Comment: I edit my question. I actually need to get thae formeted data from this table.

Comment: @jdweng I have edited the snippet out, because code snippets can be used only with HTML-CSS-JS triad. For other languages they just add noise for no benefits.

Answer (score 0):

To do that I am using something like this. but I think it will not served my exact Output:

> If there is a group with same open close day range thaen this code will be in same group and not differ.

```
            var keyMap = weekDayMap.GroupBy(c => new {c.OpenFrom, c.OpenTo});
            var openingDay = new OpeningHourMapper();
            var period = new List<Period>();
            foreach (var put in keyMap )
            {
                openingDay = weekDayMap.FirstOrDefault(c => c.OpenFrom == put.Key.OpenFrom && c.OpenTo == put.Key.OpenTo);
                period.AddRange(GetPeriodList(openingDay, openingDay));
            }



namespace Controllers.V1.Response.OpeningHourMapper
{
    public class OpeningHourMapper
    {
        public int StationNumber { get; set; }

        public string Weekday { get; set; }

        public int WeekdayNumber { get; set; }

        public string OpenFrom { get; set; }

        public string OpenTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```